# DateFormat scrambling

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am trying to format strings to dates, and comparing them.
Here are my codes to format:

```
public static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d EEEE");

public static String dateFormat(Date date) {
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

And here are my codes that uses the above code:

```
Date a = null;
Date b = null;
try {
    a = dateFormat.parse(dates.get(0));
    b = dateFormat.parse(dates.get(1));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.i("X",dates.get(0));
Log.i("Y",dates.get(1));
if(a.after(b)){
    Log.i("AAAA", "AFTER");
    Log.i("AAAA", dateFormat.format(b));
}else if(a.before(b)){
    Log.i("BBBB", "BEFORE");
    Log.i("BBBB", dateFormat.format(a));
}
```

And here's the logcat:

```
09-29 20:47:39.504: I/X(9526): Oct 1 Wednesday
09-29 20:47:39.504: I/Y(9526): Oct 2 Thursday
09-29 20:47:39.504: I/BBBB(9526): BEFORE
09-29 20:47:39.504: I/BBBB(9526): Oct 1 Thursday
```

Super weird output. Can someone please explain to me why this occurs?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think the output is "super weird"? It looks perfectly logical to me. `a` is Wednesday 1 Oct, and `b` is Thursday, 2 Oct. `a` is obviously before `b`. The output perfectly matches what the code is doing.

Comment: @jms I didn't set any year, should I?

Comment: @Jesper yes, a is obviously before b, but did you see what a's value is at the end of the logcat?

Comment: I don't know if it's related to the behavior, but I think you should name your variable dateFormat and your function dateFormat() to be different, to avoid any confusion.